# Why does my step definition only with when name is proceeded by "u"?

Tags: python, cucumber, gherkin, python-behave

I am following the Behave tutorial here: https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

After running Behave, I originally got this response:

```
Feature: showing off behave # features/test.feature:1

  Scenario: run a simple test        # features/test.feature:3
    Given we have behave installed   # None
    When we implement a test         # None
    Then behave will test it for us! # None


Failing scenarios:
  features/test.feature:3  run a simple test

0 features passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
0 scenarios passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped
0 steps passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped, 3 undefined
Took 0m0.000s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

@given(u'we have behave installed')
def step_impl(context):
    raise NotImplementedError(u'STEP: Given we have behave installed')


@when(u'we implement a test')
def step_impl(context):
    raise NotImplementedError(u'STEP: When we implement a test')


@then(u'behave will test it for us!')
def step_impl(context):
    raise NotImplementedError(u'STEP: Then behave will test it for us!')
```

After changing the step defs to add a "u" before each name it works fine. Why is the "u" necessary? I don't see any documentation for it and the Behave tutorial doesn't mention it at all. I'm using Behave version 1.2.6 and python version 3.9.6

Comment: It might be because you are actually running Python 2, and not the version you think you're running. This is from a time when unicode strings and strings were different types, and unicode string litterals where written with this initial `u`. Python 3 cleared this mess...

Comment: I'm not really sure what I did that fixed it, but it's working now without the "u". I believe you are right though, it does have something to do Behave using Python 2 before. Thanks!